# How to point two domains to directory and sub directory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have two domains `www.domain1.com` and `www.domain2.com` both have files in same host `root directory and its sub directory`. How can I point `www.domain1.com` to `[root]` and `www.domain2.com` to its sub directory (`[root/sub/]`) using `.htaccess`. If someone have any idea, please share

Comment: .htaccess and php are two different things, this has nothing to do with php

Comment: Sorry I just mentioned as it is normal php site, I removed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Use below to your **www.domain1.com** site .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.otherdomain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Use below to your **www.domain2.com** site .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com/sub/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in .htaccess in sub-directory that to be used as root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-directory-name-here/
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

You can found a detailed article [here](https://promofex.com/post/how-to-set-sub-folder-in-domain-root-directory)